# Call javascript function (which accept parameters) from php loop and process the parameters in javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

I want to call a javascript function **myfunction()** from php code. the code is as follows:

```
<script>
function myfunction() {
var r = confirm("Are you sure ? ");
if (r == true) {
//delete file from database with id b_id
}
<?php header("Refresh:0"); ?> 
}
</script>
```

I want to call the js function from this php code.

```
<?php
while(//fetched database elements one by one)
{
//$b_id fetched from database.
echo "<button class='w3-display-topright pe-7s-close-circle w3-xxlarge w3-button' onclick="myfunction($b_id);"></button>
}
?>
```

Comment: look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32666339/calling-javascript-function-in-php-while-passing-php-variables-into-the-function)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: is there any possible way to serve my purpose? help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write another PHP script that deletes an entry by ID and call it from your web page. I.e.,

```
<?
while (...) {
    echo "<button onclick='deleteEntry($id)'></button>"
}
?>
```

With your JS being something like this:

```
function deleteEntry(id) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        fetch('myserver/delete_entry.php?id=' + id);
    }
}
```

You have to write `delete_entry.php`, of course.

Comment: unable to call js function deleteEntry(id) from while loop.